# wait syntax question

Tags: fpga, verilog, hardware

Still reading Thomas Moorby book... on the IPC hand shaking part, I notice that the the wait syntax of the following two examples seems equivalent...
why  is the syntax in the first example offered at all? I made the edit in example 2.

example 1:

```
reg a,b;
reg [7:0] dataIn, dataOut;

always
begin
    wait(a);
    dataIn = dataOut
end
```

example 2

```
reg a, b;
reg [7:0] dataIn, dataOut;

always
begin
   wait(a)
    dataIn = dataOut;
end
```

Comment: The first one is syntax error. It won't even compile.

Answer (score 1):

Every procedural statement can be preceded by any number of event controls (`@(expression)`, `#(expression)`, or `wait(expression)`. An event control is not a statement in itself. The code in the first example is actually an event control in front of an empty or *null* statement. So the first example has two procedural statements inside the `begin/end` block and the second example is only one statement.

It would make a big difference if instead of a `begin/and` block you had a `fork/join` block.

```
always @(posedge clk)
fork
    wait (a);
    dataIn = dataOut
join
```

In the above example, there are now two concurrent statements inside the `fork`. The assignment to `dataIn` does not wait for `a` to become true. If I remove the `;` then the assignment would wait.

Also note that the `@(posedge clk)` is an event control belonging to the `fork/join` statement, and the `always` block only allows a single procedural statement following it. If you were to put a `;` after the `@(posedge clk)`, the `fork/join` becomes another statement and would be a syntax error.

Answer (score -1):

The whitespace makes no difference. `wait(a)` is the same as `wait( a)`.

You can put extra spaces almost anywhere, except in the middle of words. This is typical of most programming languages (that people still actually use). It's not a "different syntax", it's just that the computer doesn't care about spaces except for the fact they separate words. `wa it` is different from `wait` but `1 + 1` is the same as `1+1` or even `1           +1`.

Comment: I made an error in example 2

Comment: @hardwarenoob so the `;` is the difference?

Comment: This answer is no longer relevant since the question was edited.